# How to keep the safari toolbar and address bar display when user scrolled the page?

Tags: ios7, safari, mobile-safari

I use JQM make my mobile website. If I scroll page the tool bar at bottom will be hidden.How to keep it always display.

I use IOS version 7.0 JQM 1.3.2

Comment: @Gajotres Thank you for your modification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm curious - why would you always want the toolbar and address bar displayed?

Here's a fiddle shell demonstrating one way: http://fiddle.jshell.net/W93KY/show/

HTML and CSS look like:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

<html>
    <body>
        <div id='Body'>
            Page content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Full fiddle to see code: http://jsfiddle.net/W93KY/)

Comment: I test it,it works well.Thank you for your reply.Why I ask this question. Because I encountered this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600402/. I try to use "minimal-ui" to keep full screen mode.But it support iOS7.1. So I want to disable fullscreen and keep tool bar dispalyed.